# My auto redirection not working from other url to my

Tags: php

I don't know how to auto redirect url from one url to another. I am trying to send auto email id from my database to other url. My code is working but it's not coming back to url to send second time email id. Please help me.

My working code is here

```
$seconds=10;
$email2='shakti@gmail.com';
$var .= 'https://www.ymlp.com/api/Contacts.Add?Key=5ESTZPSGT8AFJV5Y2Y4Q&Username=38bf&Email='.$email2.'&GroupID=5';
header("refresh:$seconds;url=$var");

When it redirect to this url $var it's showing url then how cant it possible to reditect to this page index.php
```

Thanks for great help

Comment: check for extra "WHITE " Spaces on top , else your code is fine and running successfully for me

Comment: Possible error in your page with `$var .=` if `$var` hasn't been defined elsewhere.

Comment: If you want to `redirect` back to `index.php` consider using js to open a new window or use ajax. Otherwise you won't be able to redirect back unless `ymlp` has a return url option.

Answer (score 0):

```
header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );
```

this is the php way to set `header` witch will redirect you to `wherever.php` in **5 seconds**

---

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file. (source [php.net](http://php.net/header))

So, your code should be :

```
$seconds=10;
$email2='shakti@gmail.com';
$var = 'https://www.ymlp.com/api/Contacts.Add?Key=5ESTZPSGT8AFJV5Y2Y4Q&Username=38bf&Email='.$email2.'&GroupID=5';
header("refresh:$seconds;url=$var");
```

[Here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/TAWMm6) is a working Code for you

Answer (score 0):

Leave no white space , that was the only issue why it was not running ,

```
<?php 
$seconds=10;
$email2='shakti@gmail.com';
$var .= 'https://www.ymlp.com/api/Contacts.Add?Key=5ESTZPSGT8AFJV5Y2Y4Q&Username=38bf&Email='.$email2.'&GroupID=5';
header("refresh:$seconds;url=$var");
```